# Angular Autocomplete Object where Object name is different then value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-forms

I'm trying to filter an array of objects based on user input, in a form where the name is different from the value. How can I enable the code (that works for a string array) to work with an object array?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="{{ 'string' | translate }}*" matInput formControlName="example" [matAutocomplete]="exampleAutoComplete" (keyup)="filterExample($event)">
<mat-autocomplete #exampleAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayExample">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let example of exampleArray" [value]="example.id">
        {{example.name | titlecase }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
<mat-error *ngIf="companyInfoFormGroup.get('example').invalid">
    <ng-container *ngIf="companyInfoFormGroup.get('example').errors.required">
      string
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="companyInfoFormGroup.get('example').errors.example">
       string
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="companyInfoFormGroup.get('example').errors.maxlength">
      string
    </ng-container>
</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
displayExample = (id: string): string => {
    if (!id) {
        return '';
    }

    this.exampleName =  this.exampleArray.find((item: { id: string, name: string }) => {
        return item.id === id;
    }).name;

    return this.exampleName;
}

public filteredExamples(event): void {
    this.filteredExampleNames = this.filteredExampleNames
        .filter((example: string) => example.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()));
}
```

I realise this is the way to filter for a string[]. However I don't know how to get this to work for an object array.

**OBJECT**

```
{
  "id": "f0493847-f05e-ea11-a811-342cd25c7c6",
  "name": "example 1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a tedious way, you could check attributes that contain a string:

````js
public filteredExamples(event): void {
    const filteredValue = event.target.value.trim().toLowerCase();
    this.filteredExampleNames = this.filteredExampleNames
        .filter((example: object) => {
            return example.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(filteredValue) !== -1 ||
                example.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filteredValue) !== -1
        });
}```
````